# Play[2.5.x] custom body parser to get raw body and bundle it with request

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I have a post request coming in with a hmac header that I need to match the body against.  This header is created using the raw body of the request and I have no way to change that.  The content-type of the request is application/json.  Currently there seems to be no way to get access to the raw body of the request and also a json encoded body of the request so I am trying to create a custom body parser and  action to bundle the raw body and the original request together and pass them on.

I am trying to copy this guys implementation https://victorops.com/blog/capturing-raw-requests-play/ but it is pre play 2.5 so uses iteratees instead of akka streams.

Here is what I have so far:

BodyParser and Case Classes

```
object RequestArchiver {
  case class RawRequest[A](request: Request[A], raw: ByteString) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)
  case class WrappedPayload[A](wrapped: A, raw: ByteString)

  def wrappedBodyParser[B](wrapped: BodyParser[B])  (implicit exCtx: ExecutionContext): BodyParser[WrappedPayload[B]] =
    BodyParser("raw-memo") { (request: RequestHeader) =>
    val raw: Accumulator[ByteString, Either[Result, RawBuffer]] = BodyParsers.parse.raw(request)
      val ret = raw.map {
      case Left(result) =>
        Left(result)
      case Right(buffer: RawBuffer) =>
        val bytes = buffer.asBytes().getOrElse(ByteString.empty)
        Right(WrappedPayload(wrapped(request), bytes))
    }
    ret
  }
}
```

This does not compile with an error

```
Error:(33, 5) type mismatch;
 found   : play.api.libs.streams.Accumulator[akka.util.ByteString,Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either[play.api.mvc.Result,controllers.RequestArchiver.WrappedPayload[play.api.libs.streams.Accumulator[akka.util.ByteString,Either[play.api.mvc.Result,B]]]]]
 required: play.api.libs.streams.Accumulator[akka.util.ByteString,Either[play.api.mvc.Result,controllers.RequestArchiver.WrappedPayload[B]]]
    ret
    ^
```

Now I can see what that is trying to tell me and I understand that I just don't know how to fix it.  I imagine the solution is between line 15 and 24 of victorops example in the link but I don't know how to turn those lines into a 2.5 version

The custom action in case it matters

```
def extractRaw[A](parser: BodyParser[A])(block: (RawRequest[A]) => Future[Result])(implicit ctx: ExecutionContext) =
    Action.async(RequestArchiver.wrappedBodyParser(parser)) { implicit request =>
      val rawRequest = RawRequest(Request(request, request.body.wrapped), request.body.raw)
      block(rawRequest)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Play, but how about using the `raw` body parser that is much simpler. I did a quick test.

```
class Tester extends Controller {
  def handleRaw = Action(parse.raw) { implicit request =>
    request.body.asBytes().map(b => Ok(s"Request body has ${b.size} bytes")).getOrElse(NoContent)
  }
}
```

`curl -v --data "a=b&c=d" http://localhost:9000/test/raw`

```
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 9000 (#0)
> POST /test/raw HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9000
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 7
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 7 out of 7 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 85
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Date: Mon, 15 Aug 2016 09:41:30 GMT
< 
Request body has 7 bytes
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```